# Spring Cloud Config Globals

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a scenario where I need to set some properties globally for several applications. Is there support for default or global configs in spring cloud config?

Example:

```
#default.properties
setting=global_setting

#myapp.properties
something_else=app_setting

#anotherapp.properties
prop=different_app_setting
```

Here I would want for "myapp" to have setting set. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.1/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config_server) properties in `application.yml` or `application.properties` are available to every application.

Comment: I glanced right over that thinking that it only applied to the use of local files instead of git. Thanks!